# Maven failing to find jar from Project Repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a jar file which I need to include in my project. 
I am using eclipse with Maven

I created the following folder in my project on my computer:

```
/home/robert/eclipse/BobProjects/BobDiary/in_project_maven_repository/metcarob.com.lib/nachocalendar/0.23
```

and I placed a file there called:

```
nachocalendar-0.23.jar
```

I then added the dependancy to my POM file:

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>metcarob.com.lib</groupId>
  <artifactId>nachocalendar</artifactId>
  <version>0.23</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also added the Repo into my pom file:

```html
    <repository>
      <id>in-project</id>
      <name>In Project Repo</name>
      <url>file:///home/robert/eclipse/BobProjects/BobDiary/in_project_maven_repository</url>
    </repository>
```

from what I understand this should work.
When I right click on my project select run as and maven install I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project BobDiary: Could not resolve dependencies for project metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find metcarob.com.lib:nachocalendar:jar:0.23 in file:///home/robert/eclipse/BobProjects/BobDiary/in_project_maven_repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of in-project has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project BobDiary: Could not resolve dependencies for project metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find metcarob.com.lib:nachocalendar:jar:0.23 in file:///home/robert/eclipse/BobProjects/BobDiary/
```

I have followed all the steps I can see for creating an in project repository but it still seems to not be able to find the file.

Does anyone know of a step I am missing?

Thanks
Robert

Update:
I must have made mutiple mistakes. Akber found my first mistake:
I have changed the folder so the group ID is in seperate folders:
(metcarob.com.lib is now metcarob.com.lib) The jar file is now in:
/home/robert/eclipse/BobProjects/BobDiary/in_project_maven_repository/metcarob/com/lib/nachocalendar/0.23

I have verified this because the following directory exists in my machine:
~/.m2/repository/metcarob/com/lib/nachocalendar/0.23

I have moved the file, restarted eclipse and re-ran maven clean and maven install.

The error is now:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project BobDiary: Could not resolve dependencies for project metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find metcarob.com.lib:nachocalendar:jar:0.23 in file:///home/robert/eclipse/BobProjects/BobDiary/in_project_maven_repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of in-project has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project BobDiary: Could not resolve dependencies for project metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find metcarob.com.lib:nachocalendar:jar:0.23 in file:///home/robert/eclipse/BobProjects/BobDiary/in_project_maven_repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of in-project has elapsed or updates are forced
```

However I also put this project into gitlab and use CI to compile it there with the command mvn install -B
My project now finds the dependency and compiles on the gitlab CI server.

Comment: Maybe one of the two: 1) each part of the group id needs to be its own folder. 2) the pom.xml of the dependency should exist int the same folder in the repo

Comment: Thanks. That response helped see update to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, one of two problems:

1. Each part of the group id needs to be its own folder.
2. The pom.xml of the dependency should exist int the same folder in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the jar via maven into your local repo. maven does other things too except for just placing the jar into the respective folder.

please see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html)

Comment: I can't run mvn commands on my machine because I am using the eclipse version of maven. I can use mvn commands on my gitlab CI build and this just works with the command mvn install -B and since this is a brand new doker instance I don't think extra steps should be necessary.

Comment: so? which is the problem? you can define your arguments via the eclipse version of maven. that's working too! this is the official and only way. another way is to install them somewhere else and then copy the folder it created to your local folder at the other machine

Comment: all of these are valid in the context of creating a local repo inside the project except for the normal .m2 repo.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I had to:

1. Change the directory structure. I had the group ID of "metcarob.com.lib" and had that as a single directory. I had to change that to 3 directories. metcarob/com/lib
2. I quit eclipse, deleted the directory ~/.m2 and restarted eclipse. When I did a build it built fine.

   Akber's comment was the key but I can't mark a comment as correct to give him credit.

Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: this is not the right way of installing dependencies. you dont just create on your own folders and put jars. this is what maven install does

Comment: To help others, I made it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on this. If you copy a fragment of another localRepository to your localRepository

You need to remove the old repo tag from the repository key in _remote.repositories or delete the file entirely.

The Maven DefaultArtifactResolver using EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager will only resolve artifacts from _remote.repositories which are coming from one of the list of repositories in your current settings.xml